# Making a custom programmer

Tags: arduino, spi, atmega328p, programmer

I'm working on making my custom **ATmega328P** programmer. I am new to this and don't have a proper track on how to follow things. I have read the complete datasheet and have knowledge regarding the programming of the chip, but I am not sure how to execute these things now.

I want to use the **SPI** pins for programming the chip. I couldn't find much information regarding that. Kindly provide me some information regarding that and it would be helpful if I get some reference links for that.

The page of [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) I am referring to is:

[image]

Comment: `I couldn't find much information` Everything is described in chapter 28.8 of the datasheet. What do you have problems with? Currently this question isn't very focused. Also, there is already a open source serial programmer based on [Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11638).